# Setting FullCalendar config values dynamically

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

As part of a development project using FullCalendar, I needed to be able to change the value of "slotMinutes" using a browser event (onClick).  After a bit of struggle, I was able to find a way.

A)  I have a "renderCalendar()" function that contains the jQuery function for building the calendar.  Within this function is a setting for "slotMinutes", which I point to a variable initialized to 30.

> ;  slotTime = 30;
>   ...
>     function renderCalendar() {
>         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>             firstHour: 8,
>             minTime: 6,
>             maxTime: 18,
>             slotMinutes: parseInt(slotTime),
>             defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
>   ...
>     });

B)  My event handler function changes the slotTime value, destroys the current calendar, and re-runs the render function.

> function changeSlotTime(slottime) {
>         slotTime = slottime;
>         $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
>         renderCalendar();
>     }

C)  The hard-fought battle with this change was understanding that the "slotMinutes" value MUST BE AN INTEGER.  Note the "parseInt()" function in the example under section (A).

Comment: Is this a question or are you just sharing your solution? If the latter, remember to phrase it in the form of a question so that it at least sticks with the Q&A format of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Current issue is described with comments by author of FullCalendar plugin:
[first link](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293), [second link](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1181)

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
function changeSlotTime(newTime) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('options', 'slotTime', newTime
  renderCalendar();
}
```

Comment: I think you have to use option not options.

Comment: yes it should be option,
but it doesn't work for all options , only : 'height', 'contentHeight', 'aspectRatio'